# Unable to log in to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a problem with my appserv, i am trying to log in to create a SQL database, however when i type in Localhost/phpmyadmin, it prompt the message box to fill in the username and password. and i have put it the right user and password. however my access has been denied due to wrong username/password?

this is the config.inc.php excerpt

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'http';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'albert';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '1234';          // MySQL password (only needed
```

Note that i have changed my localhost to 127.0.0.1
even with 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin is not working too

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
```

can anyone please advise what i have done wrong?

Much appreciated
Albert

Answer (score 1):

Since you're storing username and password in your configuration file try changing the `auth_type` to `config`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
```

Please reference [Auth types](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types) documentation for further details, especially the following lines from `http` section:

> In config.inc.php do not fill in values for
>   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']`

Comment: just a quick question, i am in the mysql,however i am unable to create a new database, is it because of the auth_type change to config?

Comment: With auth_type config, you also need to enter the user and password fields (see the link provided by vee); probably you're being logged in as the anonymous user which won't have many permissions.